# Javascript Low-pass filter

Tags: javascript, lowpass-filter

How to properly apply a low pass filter in javascript? I'm not sure if my doing is correct or not. And I can't find a good example in javascript language

I tried using this but it returns `NaN`

```
 // Use a basic low-pass filter to keep only the gravity component of each axis.
 var grav_accelX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + ( grav_accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
 var grav_accelY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + ( grav_accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
 var grav_accelZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + ( grav_accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
```

So what I did is like this. It gives value but I'm not sure if this is the proper way.

```
const kFilteringFactor = 0.9
var accelX = x * kFilteringFactor
var accelY = y * kFilteringFactor
var accelZ = z * kFilteringFactor

accelX = accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)
accelY = accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)
accelZ = accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)
```

The inline grav_accelX variable seems like not working here's the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/toxr4z9h/)

Comment: **What** is `null`, exactly? What are the initial values for `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: @Dai Sorry it was `NaN` not `null` I edit my question

Comment: I added code snippet https://jsfiddle.net/toxr4z9h/

Comment: The bug is because you're using `grav_accelX` before it's assigned.